# Integration by parts and by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working on this "true or false" problem:

> a) For all $c\in\mathbb R$ there is a continuous and differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $$c=\int_0^\pi(\sin(x)f'(x)+\cos(x)f(x))dx$$
>
> b) For all $c\in\mathbb R$ there is a continuous and differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $$c=\int_0^\pi\sin(f(x))f'(x)dx$$

I've been giving it some thought and came to the conclusion that both is wrong which baffles me because in those problems usually one is true. What I did:

For a) I can use integration by parts and get $$\int_0^\pi(\sin(x)f'(x)+\cos(x)f(x))dx=\\=\left[\sin(x)f(x)\right]_0^\pi=\sin(\pi)f(\pi)-\sin(0)f(0),$$ where the last expression certainly is well defined since $f$ is said to be continuous on $\mathbb R$ so it's defined on $\pi$ and $0$ and takes some finite value. So in total I get that this integral is just always $0$ no matter what $f$ really is. To sum it up: For $c=0$ it doesn't matter what function we take (the equation always holds) and for $c\neq 0$ it doesn't matter either (the equation never holds).

For b) I substituted $u=f(x)$ and got $$\int_0^\pi\sin(f(x))f'(x)dx=\int_{f(0)}^{f(\pi)}\sin(u)du=\cos(f(0))-\cos(f(\pi))$$ Again the last expression is well defined, but since $-1\leq \cos(\cdot)\leq 1$ it only takes values in $[-2,2]$. So again it can't be true for all $c\in\mathbb R$. Where is my error??

Comment: What you have done is correct. There is no error.

Comment: Are you sure? I am unsure about my substitution in b). What if f'(x) has zeros in [0,pi]?

Comment: I see your argument and prefer it over mine. But now I've started to wonder: Is it technically even correct to substitute here? I mean, I'm dividing by a function that possibly has zeros.

Comment: Yes, there is a technical problem. It is best to avoid  integration by substitution.

Comment: There is a problem with the substitution. In general you can not substitute $f$ unless it is a bijection.

Comment: @pigeon Sure you can. $$\int_a^b g(f(x))f'(x)dx=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}g(u)du$$is valid any time $f$ is differentiable and $g$ is integrable, as far as I know. At the very least, bijectivity is not part of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid integration by substitution. The derivative of $-\cos (f(x))$ is $(\sin f(x)) f'(x)$. Hence the given integral is just $-\cos (f(x))|_0^{\pi}$ which is $\cos (f(0))-\cos(f(\pi))$.